# Initial typedef struct pointer (C/C++)

Tags: c++

If I define a struct like below

```
typedef struct Coder {
    float **data;
};
```

For my convenience, I also define a pointer to this struct

```
typedef Coder *AUTO;
```

and then I have to initial it by calling

```
AUTO  myInstance = new Coder;
```

My problem appear when I call

```
myInstance->data= NULL;
```

The VC 2010 told me that there was no type specifier. I don't understand what problem is here. Could you please help me?

Comment: can you post error code?

Comment: @billz: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Comment: I can't repeat the issue on my compiler. can you post more code? at least code around `myInstance->data= NULL;`

Comment: your `typedef` doesn't have a name. Also, what's convenient about the `AUTO` typedef? It just looks ugly and obfuscating to me.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The whole thing looks ugly and obfuscating.  Why the `typedef` on the `struct`, to begin with?  And while `typedef`ing the pointer is already ugly and obfuscating, giving it a completely unrelated name, and all caps at that?

Comment: Instead of posting disjoint snippets, post a **single** code snippet that, when compiled, shows the error. As is, anyone reading this question has to guess at the parts that have been left out, so can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in **C++**, just do :

```
struct Coder
{
    float **data;
};

typedef Coder *AUTO;
```

Also you have to be sure that the `AUTO` declaration is done after the declaration of your `struct` or you can *forward-declare* your `struct`.

---

Also, it is possible that [`NULL`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/) is undefined.

You can replace it by `0` or just look at the link I just gave you.

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/7ToQT4).

---

**EDIT :**
The code you gave us cannot work :

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Coder {
        float **data; // 2-D matrix
};
typedef Coder *AUTO;

AUTO  myFeatures = new Coder;

myFeatures->data = NULL; // Forbidden

int main (){
        myFeatures->data = new float *[2];
        myFeatures->data[0] = new float [2];
}
```

You can only have declaration in namespace scope, not expression like that.

In *§7.3.1/1* of the standard :

> namespace-body:
>        declaration-seq<sub>opt</sub>

which says the namespace-body can *optionally* contain only *declaration*.

This code will work :

```
// Your includes

struct Coder {
        Coder() : data(NULL) {} // Constructor who initialize data to NULL
                                // via the member-initialization-list

        float **data; // 2-D matrix
};
typedef Coder *AUTO;

AUTO  myFeatures = new Coder; // Do you want to keep it in global ??
                              // It's not a really good design

int main (){
        // You should put your declaration here.

        // myFeatures->data = NULL; useless now
        myFeatures->data = new float *[2];
        myFeatures->data[0] = new float [2];
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `myInstance = new Coder;` that this is, in fact, C++ (the tag helps as well). And regardless, I don't believe that is the Op's issue.

Comment: Follow your comment, it doesn't work. The message VC2010 gave me "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Comment: @user1432142 Can you show me the line where you see the error ?  [**this example**](http://ideone.com/7ToQT4) shows that this code is working.

Comment: The addendum about forward declarations makes this considerably closer to what is likely going on. The OP's structure declaration, while unusual, will work, and thus it alone is *not* the issue. Nowhere in the OP's code or question is there any evidence that `struct Coder` and the typedef for `AUTO` are even in the same *file*. Thus the reason for my answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig +1. I totally agree with you. I was thinking something like that.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud Exactly. [Something like this](http://ideone.com/AQvGBq), but imagine no formal definition of `Coder` before its first use. Note: your proposal *will* catch this, because removing `struct` from the declaration for `AUTO` cause the compiler to stop, not understanding *anything* about `Coder` since we're no longer even hinting it is a structure.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud this is my code, [link](http://ideone.com/n3e6q3). 
If I remove line number 15, everything is ok. My aim is to initial myFeature. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud I'm dropping my answer. update yours to tell the OP he can't be running code outside of a function. The joys of a proper constructor et'al. (wow, like I said, did't see that coming *at all* =)

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahah OK...  I will make a little update to explain the problem :)

Comment: @user1432142 You're trying to run non-initializer code outside of a function. The proper place o do what you're attempting is in a *constructor*. Pierre will show you in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In C typedef:

```
typedef int mango;
```

Now your mango represent "int" datatype.

user defined struct syntax:

```
struct mystruct;
```

use typedef:

```
typedef struct mystruct newtype;
```

Now newtype represent your struct mystruct.

Your the typedef name is missing,

```
typedef struct Coder {
    float **data;
}Coder ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct Coder {
    float **data;
}Coder;
```

will be ok.